# meta vs normal I really don't understand

Tags: discussion

I do not understand what this http://meta.stackoverflow.com is, Is this something new starting or does it have a different purpose?

Comment: [What is meta?  How does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)  In other news, I just realized that Meta doesn't have a Help Center (only the main site has one).

Answer (score -5, accepted):

The main purpose of meta sites are as below,

- Support
- Bug Reporting
- Feature Request
- Discussion